# Systems of differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> \begin{array} { c } { \text { Solve the initial value problem } } \\ { \mathbf { x } ^ { \prime } = \left( \begin{array} { c c } { 1 } & { - 5 } \\ { 1 } & { - 3 } \end{array} \right) \mathbf { x } , \quad \mathbf { x } ( 0 ) = \left( \begin{array} { c } { 1 } \\ { 1 } \end{array} \right) } \\ { \text { and describe the behavior of the solution as } t \rightarrow \infty } \end{array}

My answer so far is:
$$\vec{x}=c_1e^{(-1+i)t}\begin{pmatrix}2+i\\1\end{pmatrix}+c_2e^{(-1-i)t}\begin{pmatrix}2-i\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

The textbook has the answer:
$$\mathbf{x}(t)=e^{-t}\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)-3\sin(t)\\ \cos(t)-\sin(t)\end{pmatrix}$$

How can I simplify my solution?

UPDATE: I used the identity $e^{it} = \cos t+i\sin t$
$$c_1e^{-t}(\cos t+i\sin t)\begin{pmatrix}2+i\\1\end{pmatrix}+c_2e^{-t}(\cos t-i\sin t)\begin{pmatrix}2-i\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: $e^{(-1+i)t}=e^{-t}(\cos t+i\sin t)$

Comment: How do I simplify and remove the imaginary terms

Comment: $\sin$ and $\cos$ are bounded and $e^{-t}\to0$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: I understood your previous comment but I'm confused about this one

Comment: How does this fact help me find the solution

Comment: At first apply initial condition to renove constants $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: I found that c1 and c2 were complex, which doesn't seem right

Comment: Your solution shouldn't has (have) $i$ term!

Comment: I got the system of eqs: 1= c1(2+i)+c2(2-i)   and 1 =c1+c2

Comment: $x1 = \frac{1+i}{2}
x2 = \frac{1-i}{2}$

Comment: My method if you interest: $x'=x-5y$ and $y'=x-3y$ then $y''+2y'+2y=0$ shows $y=e^{-t}\cos t$ and $y=e^{-t}\sin t$

Comment: Yes could you explain this ?

Comment: Well $$y''=(x-3y)'=x'-3y'=(x-5y)-3y'=x-5y-3y'=(y'+3y)-5y-3y'$$ then $y''+2y'+2y=0$

Comment: Hence by characteristic equation $\lambda^2+2\lambda+2=0$, $\lambda=-1\pm i$. This shows solutions $y=e^{-t}\cos t$ and $y=e^{-t}\sin t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$X=e^{(-1+i)t}\begin{pmatrix}2+i\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$X_1=\Re(X)=e^{-t}\begin{pmatrix}2 \cos{(t)}-\sin{(t)}\\
\cos{(t)}\end{pmatrix}$$
$$X_2=\Im(X)= e^{-t}\begin{pmatrix}2 \sin{(t)}+\cos{(t)}\\
\sin{(t)}\end{pmatrix}$$
Then general real solution is
$$X=c_1X_1+c_2X_2$$
From initial condition we get
$$c_1\begin{pmatrix}2\\
1\end{pmatrix}+c_2\begin{pmatrix}1\\
0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\
1\end{pmatrix}$$
$c_1=1$, $c_2=-1$.

Answer:
$$X=X_1-X_2=e^{-t}\begin{pmatrix}\cos{(t)}-3 \sin{(t)}\\
\cos{(t)}-\sin{(t)}\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

$x'=x-5y$ and $y'=x-3y$ then $y''+2y'+2y=0$. Hence by characteristic equation $\lambda^2+2\lambda+2=0$, $\lambda=-1\pm i$. This shows solutions $y=e^{-t}\cos t$ and $y=e^{-t}\sin t$.

Now replacing $x=y'+3y$ gives $x=2e^{-t}\cos t-e^{-t}\sin t$ and $x=e^{-t}\cos t+2e^{-t}\sin t$.

Therefore general solution is
\begin{cases}
x=C_1(2e^{-t}\cos t-e^{-t}\sin t)+C_2(e^{-t}\cos t+2e^{-t}\sin t),\\
y=C_1e^{-t}\cos t+C_2e^{-t}\sin t.
\end{cases}
with initial condition $C_1=1$ and $C_2=-1$, we have particular solution
\begin{cases}
x=e^{-t}\cos t-3e^{-t}\sin t,\\
y=e^{-t}\cos t-e^{-t}\sin t.
\end{cases}
the behaviour of solution is $|\mathrm{x}|\to0$, because
\begin{cases}
|x|=|e^{-t}\cos t-3e^{-t}\sin t|\leq\sqrt{10}e^{-t}\to0,\\
|y|=|e^{-t}\cos t-e^{-t}\sin t|\leq\sqrt{2}e^{-t}\to0.
\end{cases}
as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: ,Your answer to behaviour of solutions as $t\rightarrow 0$ contains inequalities.  Those inequalities contains$\sqrt{10}e^{-t}$ and $\sqrt{2}e^{-t}$.My question is why did you select those terms?